# Energy function of Restricted Boltzmann Machine (RBM)

Tags: neural-networks, markov-process, graphical-model, restricted-boltzmann-machine

[image: RBM]

The energy function for RBM (Restricted Boltzmann Machine) is defined as
$$
E(v,h) = -\sum_{i,j} w_{ij} \, v_i \, h_j -\sum_i a_i \, v_i - \sum_i b_i \, h_i
$$
with the joint distribution
$$
\tag{1}
p(v, h) = \frac  1 Z \exp(-E(v,h))
$$

I am thinking why this form of potential function (or energy function) can satisfy the Markov properties of RBM graph?

I've read some relevant posts (e.g., [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112081) and [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61435)) but they are answered with high level arguments and none of them have convinced me mathematically.

To answer this question, I have read through [the proof of Hammersley-Clifford Theorem](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pa336/bwca_f15/hc.pdf) and I've noticed the potential function constructed in the proof is of the following form:
$$
\phi_a(x)=\sum_{b: b\subseteq a}(-1)^{|a\backslash b|} H_b(x) = \sum_{b: b\subseteq a}(-1)^{|a\backslash b|} \log f(x_b, *)
$$
($\phi_a(x)=0$ if $a$ is not a clique)

and the theorem proves the joint probability can be factorized into:
$$
\tag{2}
f(x)=\exp \sum_{a:a\subseteq V} \phi_a(x)
$$
($V$ are all vertices in the graph)

and this distribution will respect the Markov properties (by (F)=>(G)=>(L)=>(P)=>(F), see the proofs in [Chapt16 of Jordan's book draft](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10-702/markov.ps)).

So without considering the normalization (i.e., $\frac1Z$), we can simply compare RHS of equation (1) and (2) and I think they have to be the same form (otherwise no theorem says (P)=>(F)).
What I do not get is that they look very similar but the signs do not match.

To be more specific, as for RBM, I let
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
f(v_i,h_j,*) &= \exp(w_{ij}\, v_i \, h_j) > 0\\
f(v_i,*) &= \exp(a_i\, v_i) > 0\\
f(h_j,*) &= \exp(b_j\, h_j) > 0\\
f(\emptyset,*) &= c > 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Plugging into equation (2) I can get
$$
\begin{align}
f(v,h) 
&= \exp(\sum_{i,j}\phi_{v_i,h_j}(x) + \sum_i \phi_{v_i}(x) + \sum_i \phi_{h_i}(x) + C) \\ 
&\propto  \exp(\sum_{i,j}\phi_{v_i,h_j}(x) + \sum_i \phi_{v_i}(x) + \sum_i \phi_{h_i}(x)) \\
&= \exp(\sum_{i,j}\phi_{v_i,h_j}(x) + \sum_i (-1)^0 a_i\, v_i + \sum_i  (-1)^0 b_j\, h_j) \\
&= \exp(\sum_{i,j}\phi_{v_i,h_j}(x) + \sum_i a_i\, v_i + \sum_i b_j\, h_j) \\
&= \exp(\sum_{i,j} ( (-1)^{|2-2|} w_{ij}\, v_i \, h_j + (-1)^{|2-1|} a_i\, v_i
+ (-1)^{|2-1|} b_j\, h_j
) + \\
& \sum_i a_i\, v_i + \sum_i b_j\, h_j) \\
&= \exp(\sum_{i,j} ( w_{ij}\, v_i \, h_j - a_i\, v_i - b_j\, h_j) + \sum_i a_i\, v_i + \sum_i b_j\, h_j) \\
\end{align}
$$
since each vertex generally has more than 1 degree in RBM graph, the last equation is equal to
$$
f(v,h) = \exp(\sum_{i,j} w_{ij}\, v_i \, h_j - L \sum_i a_i\, v_i - M \sum_i b_j\, h_j)
$$
where $L, M > 0$.

I compare it to equation (1), and it seems the signs and coefficients do not match. Why is it?

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I think by defining these functions instead
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
f(v_i,h_j,*) &= \exp(w_{ij}\, v_i \, h_j) > 0\\
f(v_i,*) &= \exp(-a'_i\, v_i) > 0\\
f(h_j,*) &= \exp(-b'_j\, h_j) > 0\\
f(\emptyset,*) &= c > 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I can get to the expected form:
$$
\begin{align}
f(v,h) &= \exp(\sum_{i,j} w_{ij}\, v_i \, h_j + L\sum_i a'_i\, v_i + M \sum_i b'_j\, h_j) \\
&= \exp(\sum_{i,j} w_{ij}\, v_i \, h_j + \sum_i a_i\, v_i + \sum_i b_j\, h_j) 
\end{align}
$$

But still not sure if this is really the derivation behind RBM energy function.

Please correct me if I am wrong.